# In Python, how to get integer lists from a .txt file with space separated and '\r\n' delimited numbers on multiple lines?

Tags: python

The number of lines is known at the outset.

## Input file:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
8 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 0
4 0 8 2 6 3 7 1 5
..n such lines
```

## Desired result:

```
line1 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
line2 = [8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 0]
line3 = [4, 0, 8, 2, 6, 3, 7, 1, 5]
.
.
linen = [n1, ........           n9]
```

I'm currently:

- Striping the file of the '\r\n' on every line
- Getting each line using .split() to
  separate at the spaces and int(i) to convert to integers

## Code:

```
#The lines start at the 7th byte in the input file.
f.seek(7)

#Getting rid of the '\r\n'
lines = [line.rstrip('\n\r') for line in f]

#1st line
line0 = lines[0]
line = [[int(i) for i in line0.split()]]
print line


...& so on for the 'n' lines
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`str.split()` already removes whitespace from the end, including a newline. There is no need to strip the `\r`; Python already has translated the line separator to *just* `\n`.

Don't try to assign to multiple `line*` variables; just use a list instead:

```
with open(filename, 'r') as fobj:
    all_lines = [[int(num) for num in line.split()] for line in fobj]
```

Now you have a list of lists with integers.

You could just process each line as you read it from the file; move towards the end product at that time rather than hold all lines in memory:

```
with open(filename, 'r') as fobj:
    for line in fobj:
        numbers = [int(num) for num in line.split()]
        # do something with this line of numbers before moving on to the next.
```

Comment: I was going to use a dict but as @Padraic Cunningham's & your answers point out, using a list of lists and indexing is a better option. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Just split and map to int, split will do all the work for you:

```
with open("in.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        print(map(int,line.split())) # list(map(int,line.split())) for py3
```

To get a list of lists use a list comprehension:

```
with open("in.txt") as f:
    data = [map(int,line.split()) for line in f]
```

If you use python3 you need to use `list(map...` as map returns and iterator in python3 vs a list in python2.

You could also use a dict to access each list by name/key but you can use indexing so a dict would be pointless.

Comment: Be careful with `map()` as in Python 3 you'll get an iterator, not a list.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, look at the OP's prints

Comment: Yup, and I still stick with list comprehensions anyway because the OP is rarely the only audience.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, I added  `list(map...`, I  prefer map when casting but each to their own

Comment: It can be lot slower as that requires two global lookups and two calls; for *large* lists being converted the C loop speed then outweighs the list comprehension python code loop, but for a small list the list comprehension literal syntax is usually speedier. Plus I think it is more readable.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, I just always likes the `map(int,...` syntax., I think it reads like english.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham If the question isn't specifically tagged python2.x you should try to provide a solution that works on most versions, in particular on *newer* versions. I personally provide python3 code by default and suggest which `__future__` imports to use to make the code run on python2.7

Comment: @Bakuriu, true, I had a comment in the code relating to py3 use but I added a couple of lines to make it more obvious.

Answer (score 1):

If your requirements allow you to use [NumPy](http://www.numpy.org/), you can use the [`loadtxt()` function](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html#numpy.loadtxt) to read and parse the file contents into a 2D Numpy `ndarray`. This might be useful if you need to process multiple rows at once, in some complicated way that doesn't lend itself to implementing with an iterator.

Since you mentioned that the numbers don't start right at the beginning of the file, you might want to use the `skiprows` parameter to `loadtxt()` to skip the first line. Or you can open the file yourself, read seven bytes from the file object, and then pass it to `loadtxt()`.